# Merge and delete MINIMAL result when duplicate line in CSV

Tags: powershell, csv, merge, duplicates

We have to merge some CSVs that contain "Computer | Updates_Missing" on a daily basis. But to keep this file updated and with no duplicate computers I want to create a script that can merge multiple CSVs and remove duplicate computers, but **only if**:
If the computer is duplicate, only keep the line where the computer have the lowest result in update (or also delete lines if duplicate result in update)

I explain:

**csv_day_1:**

```
Computer_1 | 12
Computer_2 | 8
Computer_3 | 16
Computer_4 | 7
```

**csv_day_2:**

```
Computer_1 | 4
Computer_2 | 8
Computer_4 | 2
Computer_7 | 22
```

And I want the final result to be like:

```
Computer_1 | 4
Computer_2 | 8
Computer_3 | 16
Computer_4 | 2
Computer_7 | 22
```

I want a pattern like:

- `Import-Csv` and select "Computers" column
- If a computer is duplicate, select the line where "Updates_missing" is the less and remove the others
- If a computer got the same result to times, just keep one line.

That's a GUI script, so it look like this... :

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

#region begin GUI{ 

$Form                            = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Form
$Form.ClientSize                 = '600,300'
$Form.text                       = "Merge_CSV"
$Form.TopMost                    = $false
$Form.MaximizeBox                = $false
$Form.FormBorderStyle            = 'Fixed3D'

$Label1                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label1.text                     = "Browse your *.csv Files"
$Label1.AutoSize                 = $true
$Label1.width                    = 25
$Label1.height                   = 10
$Label1.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(40,20)
$Label1.Font                     = 'Arial,10'

$Button1                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button1.text                    = "Browse..."
$Button1.width                   = 100
$Button1.height                  = 30
$Button1.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(60,50)
$Button1.Font                    = 'Arial,10'
$Button1.Add_Click({
    # Browse the files
    Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
    $FileBrowser = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog -Property @{
        Multiselect = $true
        Filter = 'CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv'
    }
    [void]$FileBrowser.ShowDialog()

    $path1 = $FileBrowser.FileNames
    foreach ($line in $path1){
        $TextBox2.Text += "$line"+"`r`n"
        }
})

$TextBox1                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBox1.multiline              = $false
$TextBox1.width                  = 200
$TextBox1.height                 = 30
$TextBox1.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(380,50)
$TextBox1.Font                   = 'Arial,10'

$Label2                          = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Label
$Label2.text                     = "Name the exported file :"
$Label2.AutoSize                 = $true
$Label2.width                    = 25
$Label2.height                   = 10
$Label2.location                 = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(410,20)
$Label2.Font                     = 'Arial,10'

$Button2                         = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.Button
$Button2.text                    = "Fusionner et Convertir"
$Button2.width                   = 200
$Button2.height                  = 30
$Button2.location                = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(200,110)
$Button2.Font                    = 'Arial,11,style=bold'
$Button1.Add_Click({
    # 1 - Merge the file
    $CSV= @();
    Get-ChildItem $path1 | ForEach-Object{
        $CSV += @(Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path $_)
        }
    $CSV | Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\Fusion_CSV.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";"

    # 2 - Clean the merge
    Import-csv C:\Temp\Fusion_CSV.csv -Delimiter ";" | Group-Object -Property "Computer"
})

$TextBox2                        = New-Object system.Windows.Forms.TextBox
$TextBox2.multiline              = $true
$TextBox2.width                  = 560
$TextBox2.height                 = 120
$TextBox2.location               = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(20,160)
$TextBox2.Font                   = 'Arial,9'

$Form.controls.AddRange(@($Label1,$Button1,$TextBox1,$Label2,$Button2,$TextBox2))

#endregion GUI }

[void]$Form.ShowDialog()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an aside, this is a bad pattern:

```
$CSV = @();
Get-ChildItem $path1 | ForEach-Object {
    $CSV += @(Import-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path $_)
}
```

Concatenating arrays is very expensive and should be avoided because PowerShell arrays can't be expanded.  It's got to duplicate the entire array in memory and append the new data every time a new value is added.

Try this:

```
$CSV = Get-ChildItem $path1 | Import-Csv -Delimiter ";"
$CSV = $CSV | Group-Object -Property Computer | 
    Select-Object @{Name='Computer';Expression={$_.Name}}, @{Name='Updates_Missing';Expression={ $_.Group | Measure-Object -Minimum -Property Updates_Missing | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Minimum } }
```

The Select-Object after that is using calculated properties to determine the minimum number of updates missing. You'll need to be careful of missing or empty values because they will probably be interpreted as zeroes.  You may need to filter them out with something like `Where-Object { -not [String]::IsNullOrWhiteSpace($_.Updates_Missing) }`.  You'll also have to be aware of any non-numeric values in the Updates_Missing column.

The first calculated property, `@{Name='Computer';Expression={$_.Name}}`, is just renaming the `Name` column from Group-Object's output to `Computer`.  [Note: You can just specify `@{n='Computer';e={$_.Name}}`. I've used the full name of the calculated property elements for clarity.]

The second calculated property is what does the calculations:

```
@{Name='Updates_Missing';Expression={ $_.Group | Measure-Object -Minimum -Property Updates_Missing | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Minimum } }
```

We want the name of the second column to be `Updates_Missing`.  The expression is more complicated, though.  The `Group` column from Group-Object's output is a collection of each object in the group.

Here's what I see with the test data just with Group-Object:

```
PS C:\> $CSV | Group-Object -Property Computer

Count Name                      Group
----- ----                      -----
    2 Computer_1                {@{Computer=Computer_1; Updates_Missing=12}, @{Computer=Computer_1; Updates_Missing=4}}
    2 Computer_2                {@{Computer=Computer_2; Updates_Missing=8}, @{Computer=Computer_2; Updates_Missing=8}}
    2 Computer_3                {@{Computer=Computer_3; Updates_Missing=16}, @{Computer=Computer_3; Updates_Missing=16}}
    2 Computer_4                {@{Computer=Computer_4; Updates_Missing=7}, @{Computer=Computer_4; Updates_Missing=2}}
    1 Computer_7                {@{Computer=Computer_7; Updates_Missing=22}}
```

Let's look at just the first record's `Group`:

```
PS C:\> ($CSV | Group-Object -Property Computer)[0].Group

Computer   Updates_Missing
--------   ---------------
Computer_1 12
Computer_1 4
```

It's a collection of two objects.  We can use Measure-Object to find the minimum value:

```
PS C:\> ($CSV | Group-Object -Property Computer)[0].Group | Measure-Object -Property Updates_Missing -Minimum


Count    : 2
Average  :
Sum      :
Maximum  :
Minimum  : 4
Property : Updates_Missing
```

Note that `Measure-Object` was smart enough to treat the string input that it got as a numeric value. That *could* bite us potentially. For example, missing values could appear as zeroes in the output. You'll need to take that into consideration.

We only want the minimum and not the rest of that measure object.  So:

```
PS C:\> ($CSV | Group-Object -Property Computer)[0].Group | Measure-Object -Property Updates_Missing -Minimum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Minimum
4
```

And that's how you arrive at this for your expression in the second calculated property:

```
@{Name='Updates_Missing';Expression={ $_.Group | Measure-Object -Minimum -Property Updates_Missing | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Minimum } }
```

---

If you have multiple columns, then things get a bit more difficult.

Let's say your columns are now: Computer, IP, and Updates_Missing.

Try something like:

```
$CSV | Group-Object -Property Computer | 
    Select-Object @{Name = 'Computer'; Expression = {$_.Name}}, 
        @{Name = 'IP'             ; Expression = { $_.Group | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = {[int]$_.Updates_Missing}} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty IP              -First 1 } },
        @{Name = 'Updates_Missing'; Expression = { $_.Group | Sort-Object -Property @{Expression = {[int]$_.Updates_Missing}} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Updates_Missing -First 1 } }
```

I've changed the logic here again.  Instead of using Measure-Object, We'll use Sort-Object with a calculated property combined with Select-Object to only fetch the first record.  This way when we say that `Computer_1` has 4 `Missing_Updates`, then the IP we return is the IP from that record that had 4 missing updates.  You can repeat the same logic for subsequent fields, updating only the property name and the property you specify for `Select-Object -ExpandProperty`.

Comment: You'r too good, thank you so much !

I just have a last question...
If i have like, 3 colums, and i want to keep the third, how can i do it ?

Like :

"Computer, IP, Missing_Update"

I don't get how i can add the others columns of my excel...


Again, thank you so much for your work, you'r amazing !

Comment: Side question: why did you undo my formatting of the data snippets in the question? I don't think having automatic syntax coloring applied to data fragments helps with readability most of the time, so I normally put sample data in `<pre>...</pre>` to distinguish data from code visually.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Because I've seen seen enough complaints on meta about the `<pre>` tags not working that I assumed they were deprecated.

Comment: @BaconBits : I actually adapt your code to my needs, but it work perfectly !!

Thank you soooo much, I will never have succeeded without your help, If you were a friend I would have paid you a coffee or a beer :) !

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`Join-Object` cmdlet](https://github.com/iRon7/Join-Object) from the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join):

```
$day_1 = ConvertFrom-Csv 'Name,Value
Computer_1,12
Computer_2,8
Computer_3,16
Computer_4,7'

$day_2 = ConvertFrom-Csv 'Name,Value
Computer_1,4
Computer_2,8
Computer_4,2
Computer_7,22'

$day_1 | FullJoin $day_2 Name {[math]::Max([Int]$Left.$_, [Int]$Right.$_)}

Value Name
----- ----
   12 Computer_1
    8 Computer_2
   16 Computer_3
    7 Computer_4
   22 Computer_7
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !
I think i prefer to take the answer of Bacon Bits, but again, thank you :)